# ¿Como asignar imagen de drawable a un ImageView por codigo?

Tags: java, android

Intento asignar una imagen de la carpeta drawable a un ImageView con el metodo setImageResource, pero no se que parametros lleva el metodo para acceder a R.drawable.image_name

```
ImageView image;
image.setImageResource("?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con `setImageDrawable`

```
image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_name));
```

Comment: Sería necesario que explicases por qué esto que propones resuelve el problema.